# livecode how to use svg images on cards

Tags: image, svg, livecode

I'm new to livecode and I need to use some svg images in my project

I haven't find info on manual and apparently the image area object can't render an svg image

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe LiveCode supports SVG natively.  You might be able to use the browser object to display SVG graphics (which relies on the default browser of the system).  If this doesn't work, you'll need convert your SVG to a standard image format (PNG, JPEG, GIF).

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support yet for SVG in LiveCode. But there is at least one free SVG import library available. See http://revonline2.runrev.com/stack/112/SVGL.
In the mid-term (in the next 6 months or so), RunRev is planning to add some native SVG support to LiveCode, as a stretch goal that was met in the recent Kickstarter campaign. See http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1755283828/open-source-edition-of-livecode/posts?page=2.